Cannot access class 'retrofit2.Response'. Check your module classpath for missing or conflicting dependencies
I started a project with a few modules and i have problems when i build the app.

Cannot access class 'retrofit2.Response'. Check your module classpath for missing or conflicting dependencies

I also had problems with Gson but i tried something to dont have that error.
Im using TOML versions.

Version of retrofit retrofit = "2.11.0"
kotlin: kotlin = "1.8.0"

im using JDK 17 coretto
My service has suspend fun getProducts(): Response< ResponseBody>. Thats is in one module. And the datasource, who calls that function, is in another module.

But in IDE is not red, just in Build window. I tried everything that i found on internet.
Downgrade kotlin version, Retrofit version. I cant download other android studio version because the page doesnt gave other version that the last one.
Im using Android Studio koala 2024

Too little information. Share Data class and other api call logic for clarification

@Arjun That's incorrect and likely not the cause; the lastest version is 2.0.0.

Since there is no build.gradle provided, I can only assume based on the behavior ...
You may have to add the dependency as api in the secondary module, which uses it.

Dude thanks!! was that. I added retrofit dependencies to other module.

@pablomargolin Next time, please also add the dependencies block, in case of dependency issues. This makes it easier to understand the problem, instead of guessing what the problem may be.
